# How to choose random item from a dictionary to df and exclude one item?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dictionary and a dataframe, for example:

```
data={'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

city={"New York": "123", 
 "LA":"456",
 "Miami":"789"}

Output:
     Name
0     Tom
1  Joseph
2   Krish
3    John
```

I've created a column called CITY by using the following:

```
df["CITY"]=np.random.choice(list(city), len(df))
df


Name    CITY
0   Tom New York
1   Joseph  LA
2   Krish   Miami
3   John    New Yor
```

Now, I would like to generate a new column - CITY2 with a random item from city dictionary, but I would like CITY will be a different item than CITY2, so basically when I'm generating CITY2 I need to exclude CITY item.

It's worth mentioning that my real df is quite large so I need it to be effective as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to exclude all city items or you want row by row comparision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- continue with approach you have used
- have used `pd.Series()` as a convenience to remove value that has already been used
- wrapped in `apply()` to get value of each row

```
data={'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
city={"New York": "123", 
 "LA":"456",
 "Miami":"789"}
df["CITY"]=np.random.choice(list(city), len(df))

df["CITY2"] = df["CITY"].apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(pd.Series(city).drop(x).index))
```

|  | Name | CITY | CITY2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | Miami | New York |
| 1 | Joseph | LA | Miami |
| 2 | Krish | New York | Miami |
| 3 | John | New York | LA |

Answer (score 0):

You could also first group by "CITY", remove the current city per group from the city dict and then create the new random list of cities.

Maybe this is faster because you don't have to drop one city per row, but per group.

```
city2 = pd.Series()
for key,group in df.groupby('CITY'):
   cities_subset = np.delete(np.array(list(city)),list(city).index(key))
   city2 = city2.append(pd.Series(np.random.choice(cities_subset, len(group)),index=group.index))
df["CITY2"] = city2
```

This gives for example:

```
Name      CITY     CITY2
0     Tom  New York        LA
1  Joseph  New York     Miami
2   Krish        LA  New York
3    John  New York        LA
```